# How to deploy an API created with Python into AWS that returns data in streaming mode via HTTPS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fastapi, openai-api

I need to deploy a FastAPI solution into AWS that answers in streaming mode via HTTPS.

```
@app.post("/chat")
async def chat(input, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613", temperature=0, max_tokens=500):
        generator = chat_streaming(prompt=prompt, messages=input.messages, model=model, temperature=temperature)
        return StreamingResponse(generator, media_type="text/plain")
```

What is the best solution if I don't want to use a domain and create certifications?
I saw that AWS Lambda is a good option because it generates the HTTPS URL but does not support a Python Runtime for streaming, so how can I do it? Or what is another possibility?

In case I have a domain, what is the best option to deploy a FastAPI solution in AWS, like in production mode?